# simulated annealing template java

Tags: java, algorithm

Do you know any template for the simulated annealing in java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [JSimul](http://www.theblueplanet.org/JSimul/html/JSimul_readme.html) and [JAnnealer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jannealer/).